# Cannot connect externally to nginx deluge reverse proxy

Tags: deluge, nginx

I am running Deluge on my Raspberry Pi 3, and everything is working amazing, except I want to connect to it outside of my network. I have tried everything, disabling the UFW rules, correctly port forwarding to my Pi, you name it. I followed [this](https://www.htpcguides.com/configure-deluge-reverse-proxy-nginx-linux/) guide to set up a reverse proxy using nginx. I got it to work locally, but when I attempt to use my external IP, it doesn't work. Here is my script that I used from the tutorial:

```
server { 
listen 80; 
server_name _; 
location /deluge {
 proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8112/;
 proxy_set_header  X-Deluge-Base "deluge/";
    } 
}
```

I have port 80 TCP forwarded for my Pi, and still it doesn't want to accept any external IP's. 
I can provide any additional information upon request, sorry for the lack of info, I am currently away from home.
Thanks!

Comment: Some internet providers block incoming connections on port 80, so, first determine if this is the case with your provider

Comment: I did some research, and my ISP, Xfinity Comcast, does not seem to block port 80.

Comment: `"when I attempt to use my external IP"` is that from within your network, or from outside? because most routers WONT work that way from within your LAN - the router would need to have "reflection" or "loop back" on port forwards to access the external IP from within the LAN

Comment: I tested it from both inside my network and outside.

Comment: In that case you've messed up the port forward somehow